# What more can I add to properly split a string in C++ by white space or spaces?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, split

So, I'm aware that splitting a string in C++ is not as easy as it is in Python.
I am trying to split strings in this format **"57.4317/N 4.7892/E London Airport"** and **"30.8534/N 125.2235/W Madrid Airport"** by their spaces or by the "/" because I'm trying to get the numbers out (57.4317 and 4.7892). So I would get:

```
57.4317
/N
7.7892
/E 
London 
Airport
```

Here's what I have so far. I believe it works when I use a "," but for "/' or white space it doesn't work. I get an infinite loop?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

int main()
{
    string test1 = "57.4317/N 4.7892/E London Airport";
    string test2[10];
    int found, i=0;
    while (test1.size() != 0){
        found = test1.find('/');
        for (int f = 0; f < found; f++){
            test2[i] += test1[f];

        }
        test1.erase(0, found + 1);
        i++;

    }
    for (int d = 0; d < i; d++){
        cout << test2[d] << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

**How would I fix this?** thank you!

Comment: have you considered regex?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of. You should however consider what will happen if your input does not conform to the format you require (you should *always* consider this possibility).

Comment: not sure how to do that..

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach parsing the lat/lon from the string is to use stringstream to then provide a formatted read of the string into the components you need. While this is a bit rigid as far as the input format is concerned, if you have a fixed format, it works well.

The following example simply uses your `test1` string with stringstream to read both `lat` and `lon` as `double` values, skipping the intervening `/N` by picking them off as characters and allowing `>>` to consume the leading whitespace prior to `lon`. (you can easily adapt to preserve the `N` (or `S`) and `E` (or `W`) by providing two additional character variables and saving as required).

A short example would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (void) {

    double lat, lon;
    string test1 = "57.4317/N 4.7892/E London Airport";
    stringstream s (test1);
    char c;

    if ((s >> lat) && (s >> c) && (s >> c) && (s >> lon))
        cout << "lat: " << lat << "\nlon: " << lon << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ssparselatlon
lat: 57.4317
lon: 4.7892
```

Another approach would be to simply use a character pointer and the `c_str()` literal from your string to walk a pointer down the string calling `strtod` when a digit is encountered and using the `endptr` parameter to advance past the value and continue to find your next digit. You could do something similar with an *auto ranged loop* or iterator and `stod`. It all depends on how flexible your input routine needs to be. If your input format is fixed, then keeping it simple is as good a way as any.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Regular expression. It is pretty handy and it is meant for this kind of stuff. Below is the answer for your problem using regular expression.

```
  #include <iostream> 
   #include <regex> 
   #include<string.h> 
   using namespace std; 

  int main() 
  { 
    std::string subject("57.4317/N 4.7892/E London Airport");
    try {
    std::regex re("[/ ]");
    std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(subject.begin(), subject.end(), re, -1),
            std::sregex_token_iterator(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    } catch (std::regex_error& e) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
    }
    return 0; 
}
```